# How to override Django admin delete_selected_confirmation.html

Tags: django, django-views

In my Django admin. If I delete anything in superadmin or inside an user created by superadmin it shows a confirmation page. I have `delete_confirmation.html` in my templates under my admin and in my another app.

If I change anything in it or add a line it doesn't change plus it shows objects in my page which I don't want. I don't know how to override it. Please refer to the image. [My delete confirmation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuo9C.png)

Answer (score 0):

To override any template in a django project, you need to replicate the path of the template in your project's template directory.

This template is found in `contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html`

Therefore in your template directory create a directory called `admin` and then `delete_confirmation.html` in that. This overrides the django template path in your templates.

You can then put whatever you want in it & repeat this for any other templates from installed packages.

Docs on overrides of admin templates; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Comment: i have already placed that in my admin directory under templates still no changes.should i override it in my admin.py or do something like that

Comment: No, if you create a template with the same name, in the same path then it should be used instead. Perhaps your template settings are doing something to prevent it being loaded.

Comment: there is another pagination.html if i am making changes in it it is being updated but in case of delete_confirmation.html it is not being updated. is there a way to do it by def delete_view or something.